# How do you exit this websocket and eventloop example?

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, async-await, python-asyncio

```
!/usr/bin/env python

import asyncio
import websockets

buttcount=0

async def hello(websocket, path):
    global buttcount
    name = await websocket.recv()
    print(name)
    if name=="butt":
        buttcount += 1
    if buttcount == 3:
        #Do something really cool to gracefully exit without error messages    

start_server = websockets.serve(hello, "localhost", 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

I'm trying to exit when buttcount is 3. I want to stop the server cleanly without error messages. I can do it with asyncio.get_event_loop().stop() but errors are thrown that say the eventloop still has tasks.

Errors:

```
Task was destroyed but it is pending!

task: <Task pending name='Task-4' coro=<WebSocketServerProtocol.handler() running at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websockets/legacy/server.py:244> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7f74e6d08a60>()]>>

Task was destroyed but it is pending!

task: <Task pending name='Task-5' coro=<WebSocketCommonProtocol.transfer_data() running at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py:968> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7f74e6d08b20>()]> cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7f74e6d08e80>()]>

Task was destroyed but it is pending!

task: <Task pending name='Task-6' coro=<WebSocketCommonProtocol.keepalive_ping() running at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py:1259> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7f74e6d08eb0>()]>>

Task was destroyed but it is pending!

task: <Task pending name='Task-7' coro=<WebSocketCommonProtocol.close_connection() running at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py:1314> wait_for=<Task pending name='Task-5' coro=<WebSocketCommonProtocol.transfer_data() running at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py:968> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7f74e6d08b20>()]> cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7f74e6d08e80>()]>>

Task was destroyed but it is pending!

task: <Task pending name='Task-8' coro=<WebSocketCommonProtocol.write_close_frame() running at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py:1216> cb=[_release_waiter(<Future pendi...4e6d08a60>()]>)() at /usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py:429]>

sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'WebSocketCommonProtocol.write_close_frame' was never awaited

Exception ignored in: <coroutine object WebSocketCommonProtocol.close_connection at 0x7f74e6ce6740>

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py", line 1354, in close_connection

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py", line 1372, in close_transport

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py", line 1397, in wait_for_connection_lost

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 448, in wait_for
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just looking for code to stop the server that doesn't throw errors when buttcount equals 3.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with asyncio Future.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import asyncio
import websockets

thefuture= ""
buttcount= 0

async def echo(websocket):
    global buttcount
    global thefuture
    print(buttcount)
    name = await websocket.recv()
    if name == "butt":
        buttcount +=1
    if buttcount == 3:
        thefuture.set_result('Finished')

async def main():
    global thefuture
    thefuture = asyncio.Future()
    async with websockets.serve(echo, "localhost", 8765):
        await thefuture

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: This is the right thing to do.